# Why does ARM documentation recommend having only 4 function arguments? Is there a specific performance cost of having more?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, arm

Currently working with ARM embedded systems and would like to know how many arguments at max a function/method should have so that code should remain readable and efficient at the same time.

Currently I am using 6 arguments to a function. However ARM Documentation says only 4 arguments for a better code. What if I have more than 4 arguments, will it affect the performance of the system?

Comment: 42... but seriously this question is very opinion based, it is impossible to give a concrete factual answer.

Comment: As many as the function needs to do its job?

Comment: As few as possible, but no fewer.

Comment: Depends on the argument types, how they are passed and how many registers are available.  The most efficient method (besides zero arguments), is to pass each argument in a processor's register.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I just read the ARM documentation and it says it has only 4 processor registers for arguments . So i believe that's why they encourage to use only 4 arguments . thanks for your inputs :)

Comment: You also have to think about readability and maintenance.  Having 50 arguments goes into "something is wrong with the design".  A good rule of thumb is 4.  Any more than 4 should be placed into a structure and the structure passed.

Comment: Like you discovered, ARM uses registers for the first four arguments, and remaining arguments are passed via stack.  This will matter for functions that are called a *lot* in a tight loop, not so much for functions that are called once or twice over the lifetime of the program, or functions that make I/O calls.

Comment: I am a bit surprised you have a choice as to how many parameters to send to a function. If the number of arguments you are sending is fairly arbitrary it kinda sounds like you are offloading arbitrary chunks of a monolithic program to break it up into smaller pieces. If that is the case then, although you should break it up, those pieces should be so logical and self-contained that you won't have much choice over what arguments to send.

Comment: @Cyber - while opinion plays a role, the reality of the ARM ABI present a very strong technical factor worth considering in the choice, allowing answers which are absolutely on-topic here.

Answer (score 12):

The [ARM EABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf) which defines amongst other things the calling convention for C/C++ code requires that the first four arguments are passed in the general purpose registers R0 to R3.

Additional arguments are passed on the call stack, so involve a RAM access to load and retrieve them.  Apart from RAM access being often slower than register access, the transfer to and from RAM requires more instructions in any case.

This of course applies to arguments that are 32 bits in length.  Double precision floating point types, and aggregate types (structures) passed by copy cannot be passed in a single register.

In the end it is probably academic; if a function needs the arguments, it needs them!  Alternative methods of passing large amounts of data have similar overheads that make them little or no better.  For example you could pass a single pointer or reference to a structure or object containing the data, but that data is still in RAM and the access overhead remains.

Answer (score 1):

Processors dont have unlimited registers in general, so any calling convention defined for any compiler has to find some balance between number of registers used for parameters and the rest go in the stack (which is relatively unlimited).  some simply say all parameters go on the stack.

The shorter answer is because there has to be a limit and the ABI/EABI chose four, it is a nice balance for the number of registers the processor has vs the number of parameters you find in programs...

The COST, is that when you use more than four registers (which you can easily do with less than four parameters) is that the rest of the parameters go on the stack, that has a cost, if you didnt need a stack frame otherwise that costs even more.

Answer (score 1):

> tl;dr - You shouldn't care for ARM CPUs.  This is a micro optimization.
>            Let the compiler place registers by making functions **static**.

All CPUs are limited in registers.  ARM is mainly a RISC architecture and one fact that guided its development was implementing compiled code.  You may pass as many arguments as you like.  The only trade off is efficiency.

It is always good to group related parameters together in a structure.  Especially, if the parameters pass-through a function to a sub-function.  On the ARM, the first four parameters are slightly more optimal if placed first.  Consider the following example,

```
int bar(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
int baz(int a, int b, int c) { return a+bar(b,c); }
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) { return a+b+baz(d,e,f); }
```

The calculations are non-sensical.  It is only meant to provide a reference for different types of functions.  `bar` is a leaf function, `baz` is an intermediate and `foo` is a top level or higher level function.  It makes a lot of sense to package the 'e' and 'f' parameters to `foo` in a structure and to pass a pointer to the structure around.  In fact, this is perhaps a hallmark of Object-oriented design.  The structure will pass through `baz` to be used by `bar`.  When the ARM call list exceeds four, passing a structure is much the same as putting things on the stack.  The same addressing modes are available via the pointer.  Also, by grouping the variables together you get *cache* and memory *pipeline* optimizations.

If a function will use an argument, then passing it in the first four parameters is beneficial.  If a function does not use an argument, it can actually be beneficial to pass them later on.  So, if you have the latitude to choice, it is better to put frequently used parameters first.

Another issue is that it beneficial to keep arguments the same between calls.  Here is another example of the above where the `foo()` caller reverses the order.

```
int bar(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
int baz(int a, int b, int c) { return c+bar(a,b); }
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) { return e+f+baz(a,b,c); }
```

Here is a third example with the *data packaging*,

```
struct bar_data {int a; int b;};
int bar(struct bar_data *p) { return p->a+p->b; }
int baz(struct bar_data *p, int a) { return a+bar(p); }
int foo(struct bar_data *p, int a, int b, int c) { return b+c+baz(p,a); }
```

- [First example](http://goo.gl/ePA8aB) is 19 instructions.
- [Second example](http://goo.gl/F7OJW3) is 14 instructions.
- [Third example](http://goo.gl/Nrg6NU) is 16 instructions.

I choose the `-O1` option as compilers will not be able to inline if the functions are in separate source files.  They will probably all be the same at a higher level as the compiler will re-order the arguments as it best sees fit.

So, you can see that this really only matters for **extern** functions; follow the links and add the `-O3` option.

That said, clear understandable code is always beneficial.  No one should prematurely optimize.  Frankly, I wouldn't worry about it.  The ARM is generally designed to be quite efficient at handling compiled code.  Most compiler are quite good at re-ordering and analyzing code.  You are better off writing Object Oriented static functions and doing higher level design for a great many reasons.  It will also naturally result in better code.

See the [Arm Procedure calling standard](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~theom/riscos/docs/CodeStds/APCS.txt) for the register use; all `extern` functions should follow these rules on the ARM.  Depending on the machine, some floating point arguments may also be passed in registers.  So **four** is not a hard and fast rule; even if performance is your ultimate goal.

Comment: The simple functions above do not spill registers.  With spills, it can actually be better to place variables in `r4+` for non-leaf functions.  Also, the code has no conditionals.  I recompiled on *godbolt* with `-mcpu=cortex-m4` and the counts seem to be identical (or very similar).  The advice, *make functions static and let the compiler decide* seems to apply for all cases.  The AAPCS nor ATPCS (thumb version) apply to internal functions and the compiler will intelligently inline to use all 10+ general use registers, minimizing `mov`es and stack use.

Comment: The advice is for *traditional* compile and links.  If you use **LTO** or the `-whole-program` options, which many embedded systems will, it is even more misguided to think **four registers** is great for the ARM, even though the **AAPCS** might suggest otherwise.

Comment: Replacing many parameters with (for example) struct has huge argumentation at logical / programming pattern level.

Answer (score 0):

Always the design and the algorithm is more important than the actual number of parameters. If the design is good and the number of parameters is justified, if they all are used and are not redundant, everything should be fine. It's important to have them well documented.

Answer (score 0):

This depend on function-calling convention. Generally it is optimal to put function arguments in CPU registers, as accessing CPU registers is usually much faster than accessing memory. However number of CPU registers is limited so it is not possible to put all arguments into registers if the number of arguments exceeds the number of registers (less special purpose registers). Additionally operating systems limit further the number of arguments put into registers (see eg. [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions)). I am not familiar with ARM CPUs though, but the general rules (OS/calling convention, number of registers etc) should apply to ARM too.

Comment: i just figured it out sir .,.. its 4 registers for ARM for arguments.. that is why they encourage to use not more than 4 registers.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends upon your cpu and instruction set that you are using. For example, AMD64 (x86-64) instruction set has 16 registers and 6 of them can be used for setting arguments to a function call. Exceeding arguments go on stack which is obviously a slow read as compared to registers. In comparison, 32 bits architectures have less registers (8 registers) hence less number of arguments on registers.